# What is the difference between "options enabled" and "options passed" using gcc -Q -v

Tags: c, linux, gcc, compiler-options

I am looking for the default compiler flags used during compilation. Therefore I used the command `gcc -Q -v <example.c>`
the output of interest looks like this:

> GNU C (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) version 4.8.4 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
>       compiled by GNU C version 4.8.4, GMP version 5.1.3, MPFR version 3.1.2-p3, MPC version 1.0.1
>
> GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param
>   ggc-min-heapsize=131072
>
> options passed:  -v -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu example.c
>   -mtune=generic  -march=x86-64 -fstack-protector -Wformat -Wformat-security
>
> options enabled:  -faggressive-loop-optimizations 
>   -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fauto-inc-dec -fbranch-count-reg -fcommon  -fdelete-null-pointer-checks -fdwarf2-cfi-asm -fearly-inlining  -feliminate-unused-debug-types -ffunction-cse -fgcse-lm -fgnu-runtime  -fgnu-unique -fident -finline-atomics -fira-hoist-pressure  -fira-share-save-slots -fira-share-spill-slots -fivopts  -fkeep-static-consts -fleading-underscore -fmath-errno  -fmerge-debug-strings -fmove-loop-invariants -fpeephole  -fprefetch-loop-arrays -freg-struct-return -fsched-critical-path-heuristic  -fsched-dep-count-heuristic -fsched-group-heuristic -fsched-interblock  -fsched-last-insn-heuristic -fsched-rank-heuristic -fsched-spec  -fsched-spec-insn-heuristic -fsched-stalled-insns-dep -fshow-column  -fsigned-zeros -fsplit-ivs-in-unroller -fstack-protector  -fstrict-volatile-bitfields -fsync-libcalls -ftrapping-math  -ftree-coalesce-vars -ftree-cselim -ftree-forwprop -ftree-loop-if-convert  -ftree-loop-im -ftree-loop-ivcanon -ftree-loop-optimize  -ftree-parallelize-loops= -ftree-phiprop -ftree-pta -ftree-reassoc  -ftree-scev-cprop -ftree-slp-vectorize -ftree-vect-loop-version  -funit-at-a-time -funwind-tables -fvar-tracking -fvar-tracking-assignments  -fzero-initialized-in-bss -m128bit-long-double -m64 -m80387  -maccumulate-outgoing-args -malign-stringops -mfancy-math-387  -mfp-ret-in-387 -mfxsr -mglibc -mieee-fp -mlong-double-80 -mmmx -mno-sse4  -mpush-args -mred-zone -msse -msse2 -mtls-direct-seg-refs

I am now wondering: what is the difference between **options enabled** and **options passed**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Options passed** are options added to the command line, added by configuration, like `-march=x86-64 -fstack-protector`, or by command invocation, like `-v`. That means those options are not enabled by default and must be specified by gcc command.

**Options enabled** are options that are enabled and are always used to compile with that specific `gcc` on the specific system, as far as into *option passed* you are not disabling some of them.

E.g. On a clear environment calling `gcc example.c` will give you `example.c` as only passed option, but all options enabled still the same.

Comment: Does this mean that in this compilation options passed and options enabled are used to compile example.c? Why do they distinguish between these two?

Comment: Because of passed options are not enabled by default and must be passed to command to enabled them.

Comment: but in the end all compiler options (options passed and options enabled) are set to compile, right? Do you have any source explaining this?

Comment: Yes at the end all option are used. But in a clear system, without any configuration, using command `gcc example.c` will use enabled options and the only option passed will be `example.c`. I haven't got any official reference for this.

Comment: Same thing if you want to disable a _option enabled_ option: using _passed option_ you can disable it.

Comment: Where are the options "passed" by the configuration, specified?

Comment: @amn Can be configured in many ways: using makefile, `export`ing environment variables, using a `source` script....

Comment: why is -fstack-protector in both categories (options passed and options enabled), but is still not visible during compilation process?

Comment: It depends on your environment. I guess is sett somewhare in confuiguration like `CFLAGS`

Comment: @LPs I ran `cc` (no explicit flags as you can see) from my shell, so no  `make` or makefiles in sight, nothing fancy exported, and I still get five rows of options listed under "Configured with: ". So I was wondering -- who or *what* sets these?

Comment: @amn For example, with -v option you can see `COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS` is created by gcc driver itself. Take a look at [the manual](http://www.emerson.emory.edu/services/gcc/html/Environment_Variables.html) for other environment variables.

Comment: I suppose `COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS` is not supposed to be exposed to end-users given how it is not documented in the manual?

Comment: @amn It is created by `gcc` to do the job and destroyed at the end of the process.