# gcc 11: "options enabled" disappeared

Tags: gcc

gcc (x86-64) up to version 10.x produced a list of "options enabled" with `-v` or as comment in the `.s` assembly file with `-fverbose-asm`, see e.g [What is the difference between "options enabled" and "options passed" using gcc -Q -v](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38244309/3852630). With gcc version 11.x this list has disappeared.

Why? Is there a way to get this list back with some compiler flag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `-Q` together with one of the [`--help=` options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#Overall-Options):

> `optimizers`
>
> Display all of the optimization options supported by the compiler.
>
> `warnings`
>
> Display all of the options controlling warning messages produced by the compiler.
>
> `target`
>
> Display target-specific options. Unlike the --target-help option however, target-specific options of the linker and assembler are not
> displayed. This is because those tools do not currently support the
> extended --help= syntax.
>
> `params`
>
> Display the values recognized by the --param option.
>
> `language`
>
> Display the options supported for language, where language is the name of one of the languages supported in this version of GCC. If an
> option is supported by all languages, one needs to select ‘common’
> class.
>
> `common`
>
> Display the options that are common to all languages.

For instance, `gcc -Q --help=optimizers` shows output like:

```
  ...
  -fauto-inc-dec                    [enabled]
  -fbit-tests                       [enabled]
  -fbranch-count-reg                [disabled]
  -fbranch-probabilities            [disabled]
  -fcaller-saves                    [disabled]
  -fcode-hoisting                   [disabled]
  -fcombine-stack-adjustments       [disabled]
  ...
```

If you run `gcc -O2 -Q --help=optimizers` instead, you will see many of them change to `[enabled]`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's very useful! But I suppose there's no way any longer to include them in the assembly file? gcc 11 only includes comment lines with `GGC heuristics` and `options passed` when `-fverbose-asm` is used.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a GCC 10 version that emits the compiler flags *by default*, that must be a downstream addition, I think. Upstream only does this with `gcc -g` (which makes the [`-grecord-gcc-switches`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html#index-grecord-gcc-switches) default observable) or [`-frecord-gcc-switches`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html#index-frecord-gcc-switches).

So the difference you see is likely not due to compiler versions, but who built and packaged the compiler.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm not entirely sure, but I think all gcc versions I use are the ones shipped with Ubuntu 20.04, but of course that doesn't rule out modifications.