# When using g++ to compile, how to show all its implicit options being used?

Tags: c++, switch-statement, g++

I'm using g++-12 and I know it defaults to c++17. But how could I know if it's using -std=c++17 or -std=gnu++17?

Is there any compiler switch we can turn on to show/print all the g++'s explicit/implicit command line that's being used in current compilation run?

E.g,

```
> g++ --show-default-options
-std=gnu++17
```

Is there such command-line switch like `--show-default-options`?

Comment: AFAIK no option exists.  You can find out the default here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Standards.html#Standards

Comment: Are you looking for something like this?  `diff <(echo '' | g++ -E -dM -std=c++17 -x c++ -) <(echo '' | g++ -E -dM -std=gnu++17 -x c++ -)`

Comment: to expand on @NathanOliver here are the diagnostic options you can use: [link](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Message-Formatting-Options.html)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71899363/gcc-11-options-enabled-disappeared/71899531#71899531 for general info on checking what options are enabled.  I don't think it helps with `-std` in particular, though.